# SQL doesn't like decimal

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert a new record into a table 'order'. Here is the code:

```
$orderDB = mysql_query("INSERT INTO order (itemsID, deliveryDestinationID, total, shipped) VALUES ($itemID, $delivery, $totalprice, 'N')") or die(mysql_error());
```

The variables are $itemID which is a 5 digit number, $delivery which is also a 5 digit number, $totalprice which is the cost of the transaction (e.g. 137.97) and 'N' which is used in a shipped field in my table.

I think the issue is coming from $totalprice, however when I echo all the variables before this line they appear to be correct. Here is an example of the echo's and error when $totalprice is 170:

00036 00022 N 170 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (itemsID, deliveryDestinationID, total, shipped) VALUES (00036, 00022, 170' at line 1

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the brackets are correct. () for whole query and individual () for the database fields and VALUES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word in MySQL. Consider changing the table name or wrap it in backticks (eg: `` `order ```)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Thank you that worked, thank you to everyone else who commented in the same 3 seconds too :)

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER` is a reserved keyword. Escape it with backticks if you use it as table name:

```
"INSERT INTO `order` (itemsID ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). To use it as a table or column name you must enclose it in backticks.

```
$orderDB = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `order` (itemsID, deliveryDestinationID, total, shipped) VALUES ($itemID, $delivery, $totalprice, 'N')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

`order` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). It is the source of error in your query. As others suggested enclose it in back-ticks for the query to work.